# jQuery UI Tabs to work like Angular UI Tabset in getting Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

Is it possible for jQuery UI Tabs to dynamically work like Angular UI Tabset?

Code taken from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
        {{tab.content}}
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

I checked the sample of jQuery UI Tabs in http://jsfiddle.net/queryj/CnEUh/1/

But it seems that it's mostly static. I am doing this because I need a tab navigation to work in IE8. Angular UI Tabset view works fine with its design however, each tab is not recognized. So I need to use jQuery UI as it supports IE8

Comment: Yes it's possible. One way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26598490/246811

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt will it work with IE8?

Comment: I believe IE8's issues are with the use of custom elements. Using attributes or classes for your directive should overcome that issue.